# Loading content from other sites in 2014

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have to embed an site with some functionality into a site, originally from another domain, into one of the pages we are working on.

I knew two different ways of doing this: Via JQuery using the .load() function and using IFRAMES.

- I simply cannot seem to do it via JQuery due to the same-origin policy
- IFRAME does load the site, but there is javascript functionality on that site and it does not work.

What other ways can I use to achieve this? Are there any newer, updated ways? I tagged this question as "2014" because I thought some new information could be relevant for this issue.

Comment: There aren't many **new** ways to do this age-old thing in 2014, as far as I know. If you have access to the other site you could try [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IFRAME should work. Can you confirm the javascript works on its own? The can you confirm there is no javascript errors when checking console settings in dev tools on chrome or firefox, that may come from the original pages javascript clashing with the embedded pages javascript?

Also the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header could be set in the embedded site which prevents it from being used in an iframe correctly.

Comment: The javascript does work on its own. It doesn't work when I load it from the IFRAME.

Comment: Check for console errors, then check the response header for Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: How can I do that in Chrome? For some reason, the site doesnt load the form in Firefox (not really relevant to this question, but Chrome's firebug is limited)

Comment: Right click on the page and choose inspect element. Then find the network tab. Scroll till you find the call that gets the iframe, click on it, and then click its headers tab. Find the Response Header half way down, and read the access-control-allow-origin and x-frame-origin headers.